# If Statement in ASP.NET Gridview "ShowEditButton"

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, boundfield

I have a question for you regarding ASP.NET's GridView and performing an If Statement when it comes to the commandfield for the "Edit" button.

Here is the code I have right now:

```
 <Columns>

       <% if (Eval("Session("auditUpdate")") == true) { %>
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
        <% } %>

        <asp:BoundField DataField="MODEL_NUMBER" HeaderText="MODEL_NUMBER" 
            ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="MODEL_NUMBER" />
 </Columns>
```

I have a session boolean variable named auditUpdate that I am updating in the "OnRowDataBound" event for the GridView.  I want to show the edit button if 'auditUpdate' == true otherwise not show it at all.

I have searched all over and scoured my ASP.net book but I cannot seem to find the answer.

Thanks!

Comment: What's happening with the button with the code you have now?

Comment: It says:

Code blocks are not supported in this context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to set the visibility in code

```
if(this.auditUpdate)
{
   this.GridView1.Columns[0].Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: This did it!  Very easy to implement.  Thanks.